# Simple math substraction (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I need to display html of a simple math substraction.

```
treshold - count = currentCount
```

Below is my current script - it works correctly to hide/show DIVs. But I need to change the code so it will also display `currentCount` in html

```
var threshold = 100; // Number to trigger on

var widgets_to_hide = ["#promotion"]; // CSS selectors of widgets to hide when triggered

var widgets_to_show = ["#text"]; // CSS selectors of widgets to show when triggered



$(function(){
$('.ss_entry_count').on('changed.content', function(event){
var count = parseInt($('.ss_entry_count_value', this).text());


if(count - threshold){


$.each(widgets_to_hide, function(i){
$(widgets_to_hide[i]).hide();
});


$.each(widgets_to_show, function(i){
$(widgets_to_show[i]).show();
});


}
});
});


<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `treshold - count` to `currentCount` and then set the text of `#result`. Also, don't forget to to add the radix parameter to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
$(function(){
    $('.ss_entry_count').on('changed.content', function(event){
        var count = parseInt($('.ss_entry_count_value', this).text(), 10);
        var currentCount = treshold - count;
        if(currentCount){
            $.each(widgets_to_hide, function(i, widget){
                $(widget).hide();
            });
            $.each(widgets_to_show, function(i, widget){
                $(widget).show();
            });
        }

        $("#result").text(currentCount);
    });
});
```

You could simplify this even more to:

```
// use a single selector to specify which widgets to show / hide
var widgets_to_hide = "#promotion";
var widgets_to_show = "#text";

$(function(){
    $('.ss_entry_count').on('changed.content', function(event){
        var count = parseInt($('.ss_entry_count_value', this).text(), 10);
        var currentCount = treshold - count;
        if(currentCount){
            $(widgets_to_hide).hide();
            $(widgets_to_show).show();
        }

        $("#result").text(currentCount);
    });
});
```

Comment: p.s.w.g - you saved the day :D